# Let U and V be subspaces of a vector space W. Is U\V a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm not sure on how to answer such a question, or how exactly to prove that this is true or not. Should I consider whether $\,U \cap V $ exists and check the case if they are exclusive, or something else. I'm having trouble answering these questions and some methodology would help.

Comment: I think 0 is not an element of the set

Comment: Note that the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) _is_ a subspace, and is related to what you're talking about (although very much a different concept).

Comment: It would help if would would look back at the axioms and start with some easy example. Choose $W=\mathbb{R}^2$, and then some $U$ and $V$ yourself (since you asked for "some methodology which would help").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will *never* be the case.

Since $V$ is a subspace, you have $0\in V$, so $0\notin U\setminus V$.

So $U\setminus V$ cannot be a subspace of the vector space.

**Edit.**

To answer your comment, it can't be closed under multiplication since

$$0\cdot x=0\notin U\setminus V,$$

and it can't be closed under addition since

$$x-y=0\notin U\setminus V.$$

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. How could you show whether the set is closed under both addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: @James I edited to answer that additional question.

Comment: mm... there is one case where I would say that it can be closed under operations, and that would be when the set is empty, i.e. when $U=V$.  That is a rather fringe case though.

Comment: Thank you guys this really helps with my intuition.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, but the empty set is not a vector space, so no problem here.